# Get data from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

In my table I have a column `CustomerId nvarchar(100)` and a XML column called `Permissions` like this:

```
<permissions>
  <permission>test1</permission>
  <permission>test2</permission>
  <permission>test3</permission>
</permissions>
```

I try this query to get data from this XML column and `CustomerId` but it returns only first level of XML.

```
select     
    CustomerId,
    permissions.value('(/permissions//permission/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as [permissions]
from 
    MyTable
```

How to get all permissions, not only the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select     
    CustomerId,
    XC.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(25)') AS Permission
from 
    MyTable
cross apply
    Permissions.nodes('/permissions/permission') XT(XC)
```

This should return an output like:

| CustomerId | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 1 | test2 |
| 1 | test3 |